# Enum issue when converting from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c, enums

I am in the process of changing my C++ code into C code because I find myself gravitating toward more purely functional programs and am not really using any of the C++ features. The speedy compiling is also a plus.

I am having trouble with this particular bit in my header:

```
void gameLoop();
void doStuff();

enum GameState
{
    MENU, PLAY, EXIT
};

GameState gameState;
```

which I want to use for functions like this in my source:

```
void gameLoop() 
{
    while (gameState != GameState::EXIT)
    {
        doStuff();

    }
}
```

Comment: In C and you cannot use `::`; you need to use  `while (gameState != EXIT)` (this should also work in C++ and that's why in C++ you should use enum class.

Comment: Please don't modify your question in a way that makes answers nonsensical.  You removed the `GameState::EXIT` from the question and now your switch statement is malformed.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed to show both the original and modified code in unambiguous way

Comment: If you want more purely functional programming, C++ is to me a far better choice than C because it has lambda functions, implementing closures. Having true closures in pure C seems to be difficult and very verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't use the scope-resolution operator (`::`) in C ([there is no such operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)). Further, if you want to use `GameState` as a variable type (as in your declaration, `GameState gameState;`) then you will need to *explicitly* define it as a type, using the `typedef` keyword.

Here's a version of the code you posted translated to C (note also the explicit `void` argument list declarations):

```c
void gameLoop(void);
void doStuff(void);

typedef enum {
    MENU, PLAY, EXIT
} GameState;

GameState gameState;

void gameLoop(void)
{
    while (gameState != EXIT) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

As an improvement, you may like to add suitable 'prefixes' to the enum values, to avoid possible clashes with similar IDs declared elsewhere:

```c
typedef enum {
    gsMENU, gsPLAY, gsEXIT
} GameState;
```

Comment: `enum GameState {...} gameState;` saves having to pollute the `typedef` namespace, which gets pretty crowded. See [namespaces in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space).